# Polar decomposition of right shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T: H\to H$ be a bounded operator on Hilbert space $H$.
$T(e_n) = a_n e_{n+1}$ where $\{e_n\}$ is orthonormal basis and $\{a_n\}$ is bounded sequence.

1. What is the polar decomposition of $T$?
2. For what sequences $T$ is Fredholm?
3. For what sequences $T$ compact?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Do you have any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I know T = |T| U but cant seem to compute U ( U partial isometry )

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & \cdots \\ \text{sgn}\, a_1 & 0 & \cdots \\ 0 & \text{sgn}\, a_2 & \cdots \\ \vdots & &\end{bmatrix}$ (or something like $\frac{a_n}{|a_n|}$ if complex).

Comment: Oops, the above is the partial isometry part.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to check that $T^*Te_n=|a_n|^2\,e_n$ for all $n$. So $|T|\,e_n=|a_n|\,e_n$ for all $n$. Now, if $T=U\,|T|$, then for all $k$
$$
\langle Te_j,e_k\rangle=\langle U|T|e_j,e_k\rangle=\langle |T|e_j,U^*e_k\rangle=|a_k|\,\langle Ue_j,e_k\rangle.
$$
This shows that $U$ is the operator $$Ue_n=\begin{cases}\frac1{|a_n|}\,Te_n=\arg(a_n)\,e_{n+1},&\ a_n\ne0\\ \ \\0,&\ a_n=0\end{cases}.$$

As $T$ is compact if and only if $|T|$ is, the fact that $|T|$ is diagonal and $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ are its eigenvalues imply that $T$ is compact if and only if $a_n\to0$.

As for Fredholm, if $a_n\to0$, then $T$ is compact so it cannot be Fredholm. If $a_n$ does not converge to zero, then the sequence is eventually bounded away from zero. This allows one to mimic what happens in the case of the shift (i.e. when $a_n=1$ for all $n$) to conclude that there exists $S$ such that $TS-I$ and $ST-I$ are compact. In conclusion $T$ is Fredholm precisely when it is not compact, i.e. when $a_n$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: For any $m$, $$\langle T^*Te_n,e_m\rangle=\langle Te_n,Te_m\rangle=a_n\overline{a_m}\langle e_{n+1},e_{m+1}\rangle =|a_n|^2\,\delta_{n,m}=\langle |a_n|^2e_n,e_m\rangle.$$